# Need to make a query which like pivot table in excel with sum operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, qtsql

I have a Table that contains a SerialNo,StockItemId,Type,WareHouseId,NetCount
and this is my query

```
SELECT Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.SerialNo
  ,Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.StockItemId, Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.Type
  ,Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.WareHouseId 
  ,CASE  
       WHEN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.Type IN ('RS', 'RR', 'RT', 'OB') 
      THEN '1' 
      ELSE '-1' 
      END AS NetCount
FROM Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails 
 INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials 
      ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.Id = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.WorkOrderDetailId 
      INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader 
      ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.ID
```

[image: Figure 1]
I need to make a pivot table which have the sum of NetCount for every WorkHouseId Like this pivot table in excel 
[image: Figure 2]

Any Idea to do that ?

Comment: *Pivoting* is very different in MySQL and SQL Server. Please [edit] your tags to let us know which one is relevant to your situation.

Comment: Two things: 1) Change NetCount THEN ELSE to 1,-1 instead of '1','-1'. Those are two different things.  2) This very much sounds like an X-Y Problem (http://xyproblem.info). What are you trying to do with these sums? Do you need a pivot or simply a sum for each warehouse id? EDIT: And #3: Alias the tables to make it much easier for you to read.

Comment: @O.Jones OK thanks for this information

Comment: In your second image, what do your RowLabels and ColumnLabels signify? What columns make up the pivot you want?

Comment: @Shawn thanks for your comment its very useful, i need to do this sum to calculate the remaining serials or the serial which have no RS but it has SO for example (RS mean Receive Supply its mean the system recorded this serial when receiving it from supplier) & (SO means Sales Order and its mean that this the system recorded this serial when it Leave the WharHous) so i need this operation to know if any serial recorded as SO but there is no record for receiving it fundamentally.

Comment: the expected correct sum for all NetCount is to be 0 If there is -1 then this is wrong transaction need to correct

Comment: You'll definitely need to supply some test data and schema and your expected output. I don't think we have enough information about what you have and what you're trying to do to help you find an answer without a lot of guessing. What do you want your fields to be pivoted on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query to do a PIVOT, without having to put it in Excel.

```
   SELECT SerialNo, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
  FROM 

(SELECT Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.SerialNo
,Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.StockItemId, Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.Type
,Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.WareHouseId 
,CASE  
   WHEN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.Type IN ('RS', 'RR', 'RT', 'OB') 
  THEN '1' 
  ELSE '-1' 
  END AS NetCount
FROM Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials 
  ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.Id = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.WorkOrderDetailId 
  INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader 
  ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.ID) AS d PIVOT( SUM(NetCount) FOR WareHouseId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) )
```

It doesn't seem like you will need all of the fields that you have in the original query. I updated the below query to only show the fields that you need.

```
SELECT SerialNo, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
  FROM 

(SELECT Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.SerialNo
,Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.WareHouseId 
,CASE  
   WHEN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.Type IN ('RS', 'RR', 'RT', 'OB') 
  THEN '1' 
  ELSE '-1' 
  END AS NetCount

FROM Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials 
  ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.Id = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetailsSerials.WorkOrderDetailId 
  INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader 
  ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader.ID) AS d PIVOT( SUM(NetCount) FOR WareHouseId IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) )
```

Comment: No problem, feel free to rate the answer. :)